# SOlving SAT problem having Boolean And f(x) = x1 and x2 and (not x3) using Grover's algorithm

Tags: grovers-algorithm

Solving SAT using Grover's algorithm , if the f(x) = x1 and x2 and (not x3). I have a few questions:

1. is this considered a 3 SAT problem as there are three literals here and one clause?
2. I have seen in other posts where if f(x) = x1 or  x2 or (not x3). In this case, we can use Cx gate such that f(x) =  x1 xor x2 xor (not x3).

How to implement with boolean and? I can see that CZ gate can be used to get the result of 1

Answer (score 1):

1. Well, *technically* yes, because the CNF you are considering is:
   $$\left(x_1\land x_2\land\neg x_3\right)$$
   Since all your clauses have at most 3 literals, this is an instance of 3-SAT. Note however that this is also an instance of 1-SAT, using three clauses and 3 literals:
   $$\left(x_1\right)\land\left(x_2\right)\land\left(\neg x_3\right)$$
   Hence, even though it's  *technically* a 3-SAT instance, it is better described as a 1-SAT instance, which is trivially solvable in time $\mathcal{O}(n)$, with $n$ being the number of clauses.
2. I did not understand what you mean, but you can find an explanation of how to build such an oracle for Grover's algorithm [here](https://cnot.io/quantum_algorithms/grover/using_grovers_algorithm.html) and [here](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-applications/satisfiability-grover.html) (though the latter explains how to do it with Qiskit, but not how Qiskit builds the aforementioned oracle). Don't hesitate to rewrite your question so that I can answer it more precisely!

Comment: Well, the answer to my second question is here: "The Toffoli is not the unique way to implement an AND gate in quantum computing. We could also define other gates that have the same effect, but which also introduce relative phases. In these cases, we can implement the gate with fewer CNOTs."

Comment: I am unable to vote for you , but thank you. I was confused about CNF form being called as 3 SAT or 1 SAT as you have already explained.